# How to use negative margin without overlapping?

Tags: android-layout, android-gridlayout

The following is a GridLayout containing elements with zero margins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</GridLayout>
```

[image: Zero margin]

The following is the GridLayout containing its elements with negative margins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="-40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="-40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="-40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="-40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</GridLayout>
```

[image: With negative margins]

Is there a way to prevent the overlapping? In other words, each grid cell shows a zoomed-in and cropped element.
**I use ImageView for this example.  The elements could be any other types such as SurfaceView.**

Answer (score 0):

Embed each of your ImageView in a LinearLayout and add scale to your ImageView for zoom.
Pls try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:scaleX="1.2"
            android:scaleY="1.2"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:scaleX="1.2"
            android:scaleY="1.2"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:scaleX="1.2"
            android:scaleY="1.2"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:scaleX="1.2"
            android:scaleY="1.2"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I should have emphasized the last sentence of the question:'I use ImageView for this example. The elements could be any other types such as SurfaceView.".  I have just edited the question to embolden the sentence. For example, scaleX/scaleY would not work for SurfaceView based on my test. I used ImageView because it is easy to show the demo. This is really about negative margins as the questions states.